# Adyen Web-Drop In does not display ApplePay button from India

Tags: applepay, adyen

I am integrating Adyen Web-Drop-in for ApplePay from India - Though I configured ApplePay payment method under Adyen Account, I fail to see the 'Apple Pay' button on web-dropin; however, the developer in US is able to. Is there any setting that can help the developers working from India ( I am using mac/safari ) - Any inputs in this regard ?

Note - I have already tried to setting the language&region to 'US' on my mac, which did not help.. I could not find extension/plugins on Safari either, which might help!

Comment: Does it help? https://docs.adyen.com/payment-methods/apple-pay/enable-apple-pay/